# JWT Cookie sent as Set-Cookie causing "Invalid Signature" in DRF jwt

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-auth

I've been trying to solve this problem a week ago, from now on after looking for a solution in almost every forum, blog and lib's github issues I realized that it gonna be easier asking here.

I have a django app using JWT for authentication (Web and Mobile), when I change the user email the mobile app (react native) keeps sending the old jwt in cookies to server which leads to an "Invalid Signature" response *(in any endpoint including **login**)*

Here is my djangorestframework-jwt conf:

`JWT_AUTH = { 'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True, 'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': "JWT", 'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=3000), 'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True, }`

Setting this line

> 'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': "JWT",

To

> 'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,

The server won't look for jwt cookies in request however the next api calls don't find token in **Authorization Header** which leads to

> Authentication credentials were not provided

Even sending the token in Header.

At web app there is no problem with that, so I'd like to know how can I fix it, looking for a way to stop sending JWT cookie from mobile app.